# How to apply different scalacOptions in SBT for specific development phases?

Tags: scala, sbt

During the development process, there are often two distinct phases: "dirty development," where developers work on solutions, test various concepts, and introduce temporary code structures, and a "cleanup" phase to refine the code before submitting a final version or a pull request. During dirty development, it is common to have imperfections such as redundant or dead code and unused imports, missing explicit types, etc. In this context, it is beneficial for the code to compile even when there are warnings during development.

How can I configure **SBT** to use various `scalacOptions` for those different phases of coding?

Let's assume that for the "dirty development" phase, I'd like to use empty scalacOptions, but when doing final cleanup, those could look like:

```
val scalaCompilerOptions = Seq(
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  "-Xlint:-missing-interpolator,_",
  "-Xlint:adapted-args",
  "-Xlint:constant",
  "-Xlint:-byname-implicit",
  "-Ywarn-unused:imports",
  "-Ywarn-unused:patvars",
  "-Ywarn-unused:privates",
  "-Ywarn-unused:locals",
  "-Ywarn-unused:explicits",
  "-Ywarn-unused:params",
  "-Ywarn-unused:implicits",
  "-Ywarn-value-discard",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-deprecation",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
...
)
```

Ideally, when entering `test:compile` task, it would use empty `scalacOptions`, but when using `test` (or `package` or `distTgz`), it would apply the restrictive options.

sbt.version=1.7.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way (not the only way) is to make your own setting and then have `scalacOptions` depend on that setting. Then you can change the setting anytime with `set`.

For example, in the sbt build for the Scala 2 compiler (https://github.com/scala/scala), we want to have fatal warnings disabled during local development, but enabled in CI.

So our `build.sbt` has:

```scala
val fatalWarnings = settingKey[Boolean](
  "are compiler warnings fatal")
Global / fatalWarnings := insideCI.value
// then in whatever context is appropriate in your build,
Compile / scalacOptions ++= {
  if (fatalWarnings.value) Seq("-Werror")
  else Nil
}
```

Then locally when we want to temporarily enable fatal warnings, `set Global / fatalWarnings := true`.

This seems like a bit lighter-weight solution to me than Gastón's suggestion.

Comment: For the record, **sbt-tpolecat** has this functionality built-in

Answer (score 1):

In sbt you can create different sub modules with different configurations.

The app

```
// the application
lazy val app = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "my-app",
    libraryDependencies += (
      dependency1,
      dependency2,
      // ...
      dependencyN,

    )
  )
```

and then different sub modules with different configurations

```
lazy val testPackage = project
  // we put the results  in a build folder
  .in(file("build/test"))
  .settings(
    scalacOptions in Compile := Seq(
      // options for test
    ),
    // override the resource directory
    resourceDirectory in Compile := (resourceDirectory in (app, Compile)).value,
    mappings in Universal += {
      ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "test.conf") -> "conf/application.conf"
    }
  )
  .dependsOn(app)

// bascially identical despite the configuration differences
lazy val stagePackage = project
  .in(file("build/stage"))
  .settings(
    scalacOptions in Compile := Seq(
      // options for stage
    ),
    resourceDirectory in Compile := (resourceDirectory in (app, Compile)).value,
    mappings in Universal += {
      ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "stage.conf") -> "conf/application.conf"
    }
  )
  .dependsOn(app)

lazy val prodPackage = project
  .in(file("build/prod"))
  .settings(
    scalacOptions in Compile := Seq(
      // options for prod
    ),
    resourceDirectory in Compile := (resourceDirectory in (app, Compile)).value,
    mappings in Universal += {
      ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "prod.conf") -> "conf/application.conf"
    }
  )
  .dependsOn(app)
```

The plugin `sbt-native-packager` have a [good example](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/package_configuration.html) of how to do it.